# Is a language regular if a word is in a regular language but the reverse is not?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages

$$A_1 = \{ x \mid x \in A , x^R \not\in B\}$$

$A$ and $B$ are regular over $\Sigma$.

Is $A_1$ regular?

Comment: Jonathan, please do not deface your posts. Continued vandalism usually results in suspension.

Answer (score 3):

$A_1$ is regular, since regular languages are closed under intersection and complement, and $A_1 = A \setminus B^{R} = A \cap (B^{R})^{c}$. To show that the reverse $B^{R} = \{x^{R} : x \in B\}$ of a regular language $B$ is regular, take some deterministic finite state machine $M$ with language $B$. Construct a new nondeterministic finite state machine $M'$ as follows:

1. Add a new starting node, connect it with $\varepsilon$-transitions to every accepting node in $M$
2. Make only the original starting node of $M$ accepting in $M'$
3. Reverse every transition: If there is a transition from state $s_1$ to $s_2$ with character $c$ in $M$, add a transition from $s_2$ to $s_1$ with character $c$ to $M'$. If there are multiple transitions from a state, the machine can choose among them nondeterministically.

Now $M'$ accepts a string $x^{R}$ iff $M$ accepts $x$. This is easy to show: any accepting computation of $M'$ of $x^{R}$ corresponds to an accepting computation of $M$ of $x$ and vice versa.